# Cannot see SQL statements under SQL Dependency in Azure Application Insights

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, azure-application-insights

I have a .Net Framework 4.6.1 API which is referencing a .NET Standard 2.0 assembly for data access.

The .Net Framework 4.6.1 API references Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore 2.3.0-Beta2 and the .NET Standard 2.0 assembly references Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 2.1.0.

For some reason in AI the only information I see related to SQL is the following (I do not see any sql statement)

Command
SQL Alias | DatabaseName

Should this scenario currently work? If so, is there anything in particular I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Your question is not clear, please explain it properly

Comment: Check if this https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/427 helps .

Comment: I've seen that post but it's related to a completely NET461 solution. Whereas I believe my issue could be coming from the fact I using EntityFrameworkCore.